# Float + Padding = Trouble

Tags: html, css

I have this problem where one element is floated and I cannot set a padding to the other element on the same line because it appears in the beginning and not where I want it to.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uc0rh9d0/2/)**

## HTML

```
<header>
        <h1>John Doe</h1>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Game</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<div class='body'>
    <section class="body_heading">
            <h2>About Me</h2>

    </section>
    <aside>
        <section>Lorem ipsum</section>
    </aside>
    <section class="body_content">lorem ipsum</section>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    background: #f1f1f1;
}
header {
    background: #CAE5FF;
    float:left;
    height: 100%;
    color: gray;
}
header > * {
    padding: 5% 15%;
}
header > nav {
}
header > nav > ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
header > nav > ul > li {
}
.body {
    padding: 1%;
}
aside {
    float: right;
}
```

The problem is between the header and the `.body`element I want to be a little space but padding doesn't affect it.

Comment: Give `clear:left` to `.body` as header has a floating to it.

Comment: @anpsmn but then they won't be on the same line

Comment: removing `float:left;` will give full header in fiddle.

Comment: No no no, it is supposed to be on the left but full height to the bottom. THat is not the problem don't focus on it....

Comment: Oh! you want header to occupy complete page height?

Comment: @php_nub_qq ok then give `overflow: auto` to `.body`

Comment: Give `margin-right` in `.header` and making `min-height` to `height` in `html,body` got complete header.

Comment: Just inspect element and try to understand how it works? :)

Comment: apply overflow:hidden to .body
check here http://jsfiddle.net/nikkirs/uc0rh9d0/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The padding of `1%` that you have specified on the `div.body` is working perfectly fine.

The problem lies in the fact that the `header` is floated and does not have a width. Also, the `div.body` is not floated. So, the `div.body` takes up all the width while the content gets shifted because of the left floated `header`.

This can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/2fyqqwjx/1/

See the green border of `div.body` ?

A very simple solution (with your current markup) would be to give a width to the `header` and provide an equivalent `margin-left` to your `div.body`:

```
* { box-sizing: border: box; }
html, body {
    height: 100%; overflow: hidden;
}
header {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%; /* give a fixed width here */
}
.body {
    padding: 1%; margin-left: 20%; /* give a margin-left equivalent to header width */
}
```

***See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uc0rh9d0/1/***

.

Answer (score 1):

**Use below Options**

```
.body{overflow:hidden;} /* or */
.body{margin-left:125px;} /* width of left contents + 10 or 20 for some space */
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.body{padding-left:35% //whatever you want }
```

Comment: You should provide an explanation in addition to your code

Comment: There is no need for this single line change, you should look at fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Give float:left; to .body it will be enough

Answer (score 0):

Add margin-right to your header in CSS.

Here is the example

```
header {
background: #CAE5FF;
float:left;
height: 100%;
color: gray;
margin-right: 10px;
}
```